# Has a social.stackexchange.com subcomponent ever been considered?

Tags: discussion, fundamentals

(This more or less a question for the StackExchange team.)

I can imagine a few of the reasons why StackExchange would *not* open a subcomponent for questions on sociology, political science, history and so on. But I wonder: has that possibility ever been submitted, and if so, what reasons led to dismissing it?

Thanks in advance from a political scientist in training.

Comment: Note that there is a general SE meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: I'm on there too, but feared asking a question that might have known a very early answer that would not show up in searches.

Comment: There is already one for history:  http://history.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: Cliodynamics FTW!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm honestly not sure, but if you can herd the proposal through our open, democratic Area 51 process ..

http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq

.. then it will get created.

For example I searched for "sociology" and got this:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30455/human-behavior

There might be others around if you search.

Comment: Thanks, that proposal is exactly what I was looking for. It seems the discussion has never expanded on the topic, so perhaps there is no audience (yet).